# Here Map - setZoom add Zoom duration

Tags: javascript, typescript, here-api, heremaps

Here map add zooming duration.

When zooming to a location, the zoom is instant. It would be nice to zoom with duration.

```
public zoomAt(zoom = 11, center: { lat: number; lng: number}) {
    this.map.setCenter(center);
    this.map.setZoom(zoom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional parameter to animate the zoom:

```
public zoomAt(zoom = 11, center: { lat: number; lng: number}) {
    this.map.setCenter(center);
    this.map.setZoom(zoom, true);
}
```

See the [API Reference of setZoom](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.3/api_reference/H.Map.html#setZoom). It seems not possible to specify the duration of the animation to the `setZoom` method, however if the default duration does not suit, you can maybe take advantage of the method [control](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.3/api_reference/H.map.ViewModel.html#control) on `this.map.getViewModel()` and in particular its `moveZ` property, which represents *"the movement along the z-axis in zoom-levels per second"*.